# Ionic bundle issue in ionic framework

Tags: c#, angularjs, iis, ionic-framework

I have been working on this application where the user can select the items he or she wanted to purchase accordingly however after the user log out and login again and select the same item, the console display the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'itemPrice' of undefined
    at controllers.js:156
    at processQueue (ionic.bundle.js:29132)
    at ionic.bundle.js:29148
    at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:30400)
    at Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:30216)
    at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:30508)
    at done (ionic.bundle.js:24829)
    at completeRequest (ionic.bundle.js:25027)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (ionic.bundle.js:24968)
```

controller.js codes

```
 // Drink controller
  .controller('DrinksCtrl', function($scope, $state, DrinkMenu) {

    $scope.event1 = function() {
      //  alert("event1");
      console.log("event1");
    }

    $scope.$on('floating-menu:open', function() {
      //  alert('open');
      console.log("open");
    });
    $scope.$on('floating-menu:close', function() {
      //  alert('close');
      console.log("close");
    });
    // get all categories from service
    DrinkMenu.all().then(function(menu) {
      for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
        menu[i].itemPrice = parseFloat(menu[i].itemPrice).toFixed(2);
      }
      $scope.menu = menu;
    })
  })

  // Item controller
  .controller('ItemCtrl', function($scope, $state, Items, Cart, $stateParams, $ionicPopup) {

    var id = $stateParams.id;
    var item;
    console.log(id);
    // get item from service by item id
    Items.getItem(id).then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      item = angular.copy(response);
      console.log(item);
      response.itemPrice = parseFloat(response.itemPrice).toFixed(2);
      $scope.item = response;

    });



    //declare scope for both special request and itemRequest
    $scope.request = {
      special: '',
      item: false
    };

    // Show note popup when click to 'Notes to driver'
    $scope.addCart = function() {
      $scope.data = {
        quantity: 1,
      }

      var showDuplicateAlert = function() {
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
          title: 'Error',
          template: '<p class="dark">You have already added this item</b>',
          buttons: [{
            text: 'Ok',
            type: 'button-royal'
          }]
        });

        alertPopup.then(function(res) {
          console.log('error');
        });
      };

      var showAddedAlert = function() {
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
          title: 'Success',
          template: '<p class="dark">Item successfully added to cart</b>',
          buttons: [{
            text: 'Ok',
            type: 'button-royal'
          }]
        });

        alertPopup.then(function(res) {
          console.log('success');
          $state.go('app.food');
        });
      };

      // An elaborate, custom popup
      var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
        templateUrl: 'templates/popup-quantity.html',
        title: 'Quantity',
        scope: $scope,
        buttons: [{
          text: 'Cancel'
        }, {
          text: '<b>Save</b>',
          type: 'button-royal',
          onTap: function(e) {
            if (!$scope.data.quantity) {
              //don't allow the user to close unless he enters note
              e.preventDefault();
            } else {
              return $scope.data.quantity;
            }
          }
        }, ]
      });
      myPopup.then(function(res) {
        console.log(res);
        if (res != undefined) {
          $scope.data.quantity = res;
          item.quantity = res;
          if ($scope.request.special == '') {
            item.specialRequest = "None";
          } else {
            item.specialRequest = $scope.request.special;
          }
          if ($scope.itemRequest) {
            item.itemRequest = $scope.request.item;
          } else {
            item.itemRequest = "None";
          }

          if (Cart.isDuplicate(item)) {
            showDuplicateAlert();
          } else {
            Cart.add(item);
            showAddedAlert();
          }

        }

      });
    };
  })
```

Comment: can you post the code of controllers.js? (lines 140 to 180)

Comment: what is the line 156?

Comment: Hi, line 156 is: response.itemPrice = parseFloat(response.itemPrice).toFixed(2);

Comment: ok.. the problem is that your `response` is undefined than you cannot access to the item `itemPrice`

Comment: The first time ,it works correctly,the response do contain some values,but after i logout and login back again, i will get undefined  value when i click on the item. I suppose it is some sort of ionic bundle problem.

Comment: check your response (or maybe the id that you send when tap on a item can be undefined and then the response is undefined).

Comment: the id is defined. They call the wrong service in the process queue.